# Lua - WoW related

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I have been playing with Lua and World of Warcraft (A.K.A WoW) for about 2 days.

My problem is that when I use the following code (not as a macro, but as an AddOn)

```
TimeManagerClockButton:Hide()
```

it throws me the following error message.

Message: Interface\AddOns\WeakCloudUI\WeakCloudUI.lua:22: attempt to index global 'TimeManagerClockButton' (a nil value) 
Time: 07/04/15 21:38:16 
Count: 1 
Stack: Interface\AddOns\WeakCloudUI\WeakCloudUI.lua:22: in main chunk

Locals: (*temporary) = nil 
(*temporary) = nil 
(*temporary) =  
(*temporary) = 13 
(*temporary) = "OUTLINE" 
(*temporary) = true 
(*temporary) = 30 
(*temporary) =  
(*temporary) = nil 
(*temporary) = nil 
(*temporary) = "attempt to index global 'TimeManagerClockButton' (a nil value)"

It works perfectly well as a macro, but the problem happens when I use that code on AddOn (lua file).

Can someone please tell me what the problem is?

Thank you.

Comment: best guess is you don't have initialize TimeManagerClockButton, you you are trying to use it before entering the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, you are probably running the code before TimeManagerClockButton exists because the addon code has not yet loaded.

You may be able to [require](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/API_LoadAddOn) the other addon to load by using

```
assert(LoadAddOn("Blizzard_TimeManager"))
```

You may also try delaying your addon code to run later by using an [event](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/AddOn_loading_process#Saved_variables_loading) or a timer.

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply. I was too newb when I asked this question D: Just like you've commented, the code was ran before TimeManagerClockButton exists. Thank you for your help!